# need an Arrayformula to summarize daily transactions into 2 tables ( google sheets )

Tags: google-sheets-formula

i need to make a report based on (A:E) to spit out the current day summary and detail

link to google sheets workbook [`SHARED STACK OVERFLOW`](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bWhKFWpirrAtzwfXjJn4UbrLI-4usqt8dQoz3hbryqo/edit#gid=2084151412)

my attempt range is I2:R18

my end result range should be I23:L53

```
 DAILY ACH BATCH SUMMARY 08/04/2023 Friday  TOTAL $ 611,481.1           
VENDOR  AMOUNT  AP COUNT    REMITTANCE MEMO
VENDOR  0.00    1   
VENID821 C  85,058.00   1   
VENIDD NAM  10,000.00   1   
VENIDEHEMI  9,717.12    1   717721 / 0314697
VENIDMERSO  2,352.00    1   717678 / 2113004
VENIDNCED   2,000.00    1   
VENIDOLGAT  36,583.11   6   717606 / 036944*717610 / 036942*717607 / 036943*717609 / 028817*717601 / 037102*717604 / 030297
VENIDON 292,235.00  1   717280 (42954) / 4147
VENIDON WE  35,608.40   1   717683 / 134322
VENIDONNEC  134,370.00  1   717729 / 1201
VENIDTRIC   3,557.47    1   9821P
            
 DAILY ACH BATCH DETAIL REPORT 08/04/2023 Friday  TOTAL $ 611,481.          
TYPE    VENDOR  REMITTANCE MEMO AMOUNT
WIRE HSBC   VENID821 C      85,058.00
ACH VENIDD NAM      10,000.00
ACH VENIDEHEMI  717721 / 0314697    9,717.12
ACH VENIDMERSO  717678 / 2113004    2,352.00
ACH VENIDNCED       2,000.00
ACH VENIDOLGAT  717606 / 036944 13,485.54
ACH VENIDOLGAT  717610 / 036942 4,498.20
ACH VENIDOLGAT  717607 / 036943 3,203.62
ACH VENIDOLGAT  717609 / 028817 3,969.00
ACH VENIDOLGAT  717601 / 037102 9,774.03
ACH VENIDOLGAT  717604 / 030297 1,652.72
WIRE    VENIDON 717280 (42954) / 4147   292,235.00
ACH VENIDON WE  717683 / 134322 35,608.40
ACH VENIDONNEC  717729 / 1201   134,370.00
ACH VENIDTRIC   9821P   3,557.47
```

i tried to make 2 arrays not succesfully

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a possible solution. It first takes the date (I used TODAY()-1 because there's no actual data for today, modify it as needed. FILTERs the vendors in the second line, sums the amounts in the third one, counts the sales in the 4th one, JOINs the memos, and in the last line, stacks all the values. It has an extra line with totals that you can remove

```
=LET(date,TODAY()-1,
vendors,SORT(TOCOL(UNIQUE(FILTER(C2:C,A2:A=date)),1)),
amounts,BYROW(vendors,LAMBDA(vendor,SUMIFS(E2:E,A2:A,date,C2:C,vendor))),
counts,BYROW(vendors,LAMBDA(vendor,COUNTIFS(C2:C,vendor,A2:A,date))),
memos,BYROW(vendors,LAMBDA(vendor,TEXTJOIN("*",1,FILTER(D2:D,A2:A=date,C2:C=vendor)))),
{vendors,amounts,counts,memos;
"TOTALS",SUM(amounts),SUM(counts),""})
```

[image]

For the second chart you can just use FILTER:

```
=FILTER(B:E,A:A=TODAY()-1)
```

[image]

Comment: 1 More request , if the Remittance memo is blank , i would like to auto popolate with " "AP " & "TODAY()"

Comment: First of all, you could appreciate the work already done! Do you expect that each line that is empty in the original data has that code?, So a vendor could happen to have more than once this same AP&TODAY()

Comment: HI Martin , i am pretty sure i said thank you for your help , i do appreciate it * yes , we have more than 1 line for same AP&TODAY()